# Are some questions hotter than others?

Tags: support, hot-questions, views

Why can some Hot Network Questions gather over 1000 views in a day, when others only get 100 in two days? Are they shown in the "Hot Network Questions" side bar with different frequency? Or it is just the attractiveness of the site and title of the question?

Comment: I'd be very curious to see an example of a HNQ question which started there for two days while gathering less than 100 views. Got a link to provide?

Comment: Yeah, that puzzles me as well. I've gathered some information during the last year about question views during their presence in the HNQ, so I can probably figure out what the minimum was.

Comment: @Jenayah both asked yesterday on the same site: 721 views https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229116/account-creation-and-log-in-system and 95 views https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229073/pure-python-range-implementation

Comment: That's why I am asking. 7 times difference with the same site? Can't believe they are shown with the same frequency.

Comment: Asked today, 762 views https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229152/algorithm-for-competing-cells-of-0s-and-1s Really random selection?

Comment: I really doubt the second one stayed in the HNQ for long. Do you have data on it?

Comment: @Jenayah what kind of data do you mean? All I know that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/229073/revisions says "Became Hot Network Question occurred yesterday". I also doubt that it really occured.

Comment: How long it stayed on HNQ. If it stayed there for 15 minutes before being thrown out by hotter stuff, then the 95 views aren't unexpectedly low.

Comment: Oh it can be thrown out... Don't know about it and how it works, sorry. There is no informaion in the revision history about being thrown out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they shown in the "Hot Network Questions" side bar with different frequency?

No, that's just a random selection. The only places the order matters are in the complete lists found on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and in the mobile apps (not in the feed itself, but when you visit 'More hot network questions').

> Or it is just the attractiveness of the site and title of the question?

Yes, that's part of it. That's why it's important for questions to have a proper title, one that covers the topic of the question. If it's [clickbait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait), it will probably get more views.

The other part is the *time* which the question spends in the Hot Network Questions list, which is reinforced by the number of views, since more views tend to lead to more votes and often to more answers as well, increasing the question's hotness.